# Can I add multiple new items referring to each other with Entity Framework without saving the context first?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I’ve got 3 tables:  Inventory, InventoryLocations, InventoryCounts.  Inventory holds item descriptions.  InventoryLocations holds location description.  InventoryCounts is a bridge table with the InventoryID, LocationID, and # of items at that location.

When I import a file, all 3 can be new.  So, within the context, I would like to add the inventory item and let the DB/EF generate the InventoryID.  Then, I would like to add a location description letting the DB generate the ID.  Then, add a new record to the InventoryCounts table using the ID generated for the Inventory item as well as the ID generated for the Location.  I would also like to do this using one context and only one SaveChanges.

From what I have read, this seems totally doable, but I don’t know enough about the Navigation properties or Fluent API to make this work.  Using the code below, doesn’t work.

I know I can probably parse through the data and pull in all locations, then save.  Then pull in all inventory, then save.  Then add the counts.  This is just inefficient.

The sample code follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
Imports System.Data.Entity.Spatial

Public Class Test
'' Test Class
Public Sub test()

    Using ctx As New PIOCContext
        Dim Inv = ctx.App_Inventory
        Dim Loc = ctx.App_InventoryLocations
        Dim InvCounts = ctx.App_InventoryCounts

        Dim i As New App_Inventory() With {.ItemName = "Widget"}
        Inv.add(i)

        Dim l As New App_InventoryLocation() With {.Location = "Foo"}
        Loc.Add(l)

        Dim cnt As New App_InventoryCount() With {.InventoryID = i.InventoryID, .Qty = 1, .QtyUOM = "Each", .LocationID = l.LocationID}
        InvCounts.Add(cnt)

        ctx.SaveChanges()
    End Using

End Sub

End Class


'' Models
<Table("dev.App_InventorySubLocations")>
Partial Public Class App_InventoryLocation
<Key>
<Column(TypeName:="uint"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>
Public Property LocationID As Long

<Required>
<StringLength(45)>
Public Property Location As String

End Class


<Table("dev.App_InventoryCounts")>
Partial Public Class App_InventoryCount


<Key>
<Column(Order:=0, TypeName:="uint")>
<DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
Public Property InventoryID As Long

<Key>
<Column(Order:=1, TypeName:="uint")>
<DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
Public Property LocationID As Long

<Column(TypeName:="uint")>
Public Property Qty As Long

<Required>
<StringLength(45)>
Public Property QtyUOM As String

Public Overridable Property Inventory As App_Inventory
Public Overridable Property Location As App_InventoryLocation

End Class

Partial Public Class MyContext
    Inherits DbContext
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=MyContext")
End Sub

Public Overridable Property App_Inventory As DbSet(Of App_Inventory)
Public Overridable Property App_InventoryCounts As DbSet(Of App_InventoryCount)
Public Overridable Property App_InventoryLocations As DbSet(Of App_InventoryLocation)

End Class
```

Comment: Just give `InventoryCount` navigation properties `Inventory` and `Location` and assign `Inventory = i` and `Location = l`.

Comment: Thanks Gert!  I guess I was just over thinking it.  I un-officially flag your comment as the answer (since I can't officially do it).

Answer (score 0):

As Gert suggested above, the answer was to change the code to add to read:

```
Dim cnt As New App_InventoryCount() With {.InventoryID = i.InventoryID, .Qty = 1, .QtyUOM = "Each", .Location = l}
```

As a side note, I also needed to change all of my unsigned integers to integers.  Apparently Entity Framework doesn't like UInt's or big UInt's.
[See post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895598/why-cant-i-insert-record-with-foreign-key-in-a-single-server-request/2950620)